# Azure DevOps Pipelines, how can the job know it was triggered from a Schedule?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an Azure DevOps system up and running, with triggers to run the pipeline due to PRs as well as a nightly schedule, like so:

```
trigger:
 batch: true
 branches:
  include:
   - main
   - release/*
   - pre-release/*

schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: Daily midnight build
    branches:
      include:
        #- main
        #- release/*
        - pre-release/*
    always: false
```

Is there a way to let the job know that's being called from a Schedule rather than a PR? I'd like to add another series of more rigorous tests, but just with nightlies, as part of the usual job.

Perhaps setting a variable that can be checked later in the pipeline.

Comment: did that work for you ?

Comment: Checking the `Build.Reason` worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `Build.Reason` [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

In your case checking if `$(Build.Reason)` equals **Schedule** should work.

> Build.Reason. The event that caused the build to run.
>
> - `Manual`: A user manually queued the build.
> - `IndividualCI`: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in.
> - `BatchedCI`: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in, and the Batch changes was selected.
> - `Schedule`: Scheduled trigger.
> - `ValidateShelvese`: A user manually queued the build of a specific TFVC shelveset.
> - `CheckInShelveset`: Gated check-in trigger.
> - `PullRequest`: The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build.
> - `ResourceTrigger`: The build was triggered by a resource trigger or it was triggered by another build.